# GHCI infinite loop in Binary Search Tree

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have this implementation of a Binary Search Tree in Haskell

```
data BST = Nil | Node (BST) Int (BST) deriving Show

emptyTree :: BST
emptyTree = Nil

isEmptyTree :: BST -> Bool
isEmptyTree Nil = True
isEmptyTree _ = False

leftChild :: BST -> BST
leftChild Nil = Nil
leftChild (Node l k r) = l

rightChild :: BST -> BST
rightChild Nil = Nil
rightChild (Node l k r) = r

root :: BST -> Int
root Nil = error "Empty Tree"
root (Node l k r) = k

insert_r :: BST -> Int -> BST
insert_r Nil k = Node Nil k Nil
insert_r n@(Node l x r) k
    | k < x = Node (insert_r l k) x r
    | k > x = Node l x (insert_r r k)
    | otherwise = n
```

I'm trying to test it inserting some values into the tree. This is a sample testing sequence:

```
t = Nil
t = insert_r t 2
t = insert_r t 3
t = insert_r t 1
```

When i try to run this in GHCi, at the moment of checking "t" value, i get an infinite loop.
However, if I assign the result of every insertion to a new variable, as this:

```
v = insert_r t 2
u = insert_r v 1
```

Checking the value of "u" works perfectly. Does this have to do with Haskell's lazy evaluation, or am i coding something wrong in the BST implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All this stuff about your tree is quite unrelated to the root cause here, which is that haskell's `=` is not an assignment operator, but a definition. Importantly, it permits recursion, allowing a value to refer to itself, for example `xs = 1 : xs` producing an infinite list of 1s.

So you are not incrementally building up one tree via three insertions, but rather defining three unrelated trees, each self-referential and therefore circular. You would have the same problem if you simply wrote `x = x`.

If you want to name steps in a computation, you must give each a different name, because you cannot modify existing bindings.